# How do I fix the errors for each line when connecting SSH to github?

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel, github-for-windows

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
/c/Users/user/.ssh/config line 1: no argument after keyword "host*"
/c/Users/user/.ssh/config line 5: no argument after keyword "identityfile~/.ssh/id_ed25519"
/c/Users/user/.ssh/config: terminating, 2 bad configuration options
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing some mandatory whitespace in your `.ssh/config` file. `host *` and `identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`.

Comment: @chepner I agree, except for `IdentityFile`, which is indeed *without* space between `Identity` and `File`.

Comment: Oops, that's was autocorrect messing with me. I meant `identityfile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do this was delete the config file from .SSH config (after making a copy), and then reconnect to the SSH you need. You can re-add them if you are using a tool like remote explorer in VScode and it will create a new config file for you. The ssh config file is overwriting the default ssh parameters when the connection is happening.